# How can I use .then() on an Array?`

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I'm doing a lot of promise based operations in an Express/Sequelize app. In order to control the data flow, I want to follow the promise model as closely as possible.

Here's a snippet of what I'm currently doing:

```
 AreaList.forEach( area => {
      distances.push({
        target: tgt,
        source: area,
        distance: areaController.calcDist(tgt, area),
        country: areaController.determineCountry(area)
      }).then(() => { //this is where I would like to have the .then() function, but get the error.
      distances.sort((a1, a2) =>{
        return a1.distance - a2.distance;
      }).filter(area => area.country === country)
      .forEach(area => {
       Insider.findAll({
        where: {
         areaCode: area.source,
         country: area.country,
         language: language,
         gender: gender
        }
      }).then( insider => {
        returnUsers.push(insiders);
      }).then(_ => {
        returnUsers = returnUsers.splice(0,10);
        res.status(200).send(returnUsers);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

How can I either provide the `.then()` for the Array, or simulate the `.then()`?

Comment: The array's `push` function returns the new number of elements in the array and there is no `then` function for numbers. Since the `push` function does not work asynchronously, there is no need to work with promises here, simply `push` the new item to the array, then continue with the `sort`.

Comment: You don't need a `then` function, just end command, write a gentle `;` and return next line : the push function is **synchronous**.

Comment: I assume `AreaList` is an array of items. Do you want to process one item after another (serial), all at the same time (parallel) or parallel but maximum x amount per period (like max 5 per second) or max x amount active (like no more than 5 active connections)? What are the functions in your code that are asynchronous? Are the `areacontroller` functions synchronous or asynchronous?  I assume `Insider.findAll` is asynchronous, is that the only asynchronous function?

Comment: And forgot one. If one fails do you want the ones that succeeded or just fail the whole thing?

Comment: `AreaList` should be processed in serial. `areaController` is the module this code is from, and yes, the `findAll()` functions are async, which is why I was getting confused from this mix of Async and Sync code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is mixing synchronous code with asynchronous code. In your code snippet above you have various pieces of synchronous code. `AreaList.forEach`, `distances.push`, `distances.sort` are all synchronous operations.

What it seems to me you are trying to do is process some code while pushing it into an array, this may or may not be asynchronous (`areaController.calcDist(tgt, area)`).

I would rewrite something like this assuming `areaController.calcDist(tgt, area)` is a synchronous operation:

```
let distances = AreaList.map(area => {
  return {
    target: tgt,
    source: area,
    distance: areaController.calcDist(tgt, area),
    country: areaController.determineCountry(area)
  };
})
.sort((a1, a2) =>{
    return a1.distance - a2.distance;
})
.filter(area => area.country === country);

let findUsers = distances.map(area => {
   return Insider.findAll({
    where: {
     areaCode: area.source,
     country: area.country,
     language: language,
     gender: gender
    }
   });
  });

Promise.all(findUsers).then(users => {
  let returnUsers = users.splice(0, 10);
  res.status(200).send(returnUsers);
})
.catch(err => {
  //handle errors
});
```

Comment: Oh glob! that looks beautiful! I'm going to reimplement as this!

Answer (score 0):

then() is a function provided by javascript promises resolve. if you want to do a sequence of stuff when going through each item in your AreaList, you should do this:

```
pushDistances(distance) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        distance.push(distance);
        resolve();
    });
```

with the resolve() function, you can either just resolve() it without anything or attach something that you'd like to resolve with: like the distance you just pushed or the updated distances array with the newly pushed distance.

```
resolve(distances) or resolve(distance);
```

and then in your .then(), you get either distances or distance, based on what you resolved with. like this:

```
pushDistances().then((distance or distances) => {
  within this function you have access to distance or distances: based on what you resolved with. 
});
```

and then you can just chain a bunch of functions that return promises

```
pushDistances().then(() => anotherFunctionThatReturnsPromise()).then(() => {})
```

that's a general overview of how promises work. You should look more into 
[Javascript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to see how you can chain promises.